# Downloading ROS Indigo on a Pi - rosinstall_generator: command not found?

Tags: ros

I've been following the online tutorial for Raspbian Jessie given on the ROS wiki in order to install ROS Indigo on my Raspberry Pi 2. Whenever I get to the step where I install ROS-Comm (after following all the steps above in the tutorial), I get the error: bash: rosinstall_generator: command not found.

What can I do?

These are the steps I've done so far:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get upgrade

$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-setuptools python-yaml python-distribute python-docutils python-dateutil python-six

$ sudo pip install rosdep rosinstall_generator wstool rosinstall

$ sudo rosdep init

$ rosdep update

$ mkdir ~/ros_catkin_ws

$ cd ~/ros_catkin_ws

$ rosinstall_generator ros_comm --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only --exclude roslisp --tar > indigo-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall
```

---> It's this last step where I get the error:

```
bash: rosinstall_generator: command not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that rosinstall_generator is not installed
i had similar problem and i noticed that when i tried to install "python-rosinstall_generator" it returned

```
No package python-rosinstall_generator available.
```

I found out that the package is not included in the disto i'm using so it needed to be built from source.

also i noticed that pip is not installed on my machine so another soultion could be to install pip and than run the pip command